# Why Cytoscape.js graph is not spanning the entire width of a bootstrap card?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using [cola](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola) layout to render a Cytoscape graph inside a bootstrap card element. However, the graph mostly tries to span vertically and in spite of having plenty of spaces in the horizontal direction, it does not span there. See the following screenshot.

[image]

To reproduce the issue please use the following Electron fiddle gist:
https://gist.github.com/wasimaftab/33ab4ef9134b8c2b4c7afed4392b6520

I'm using `cytoscape@3.16.1` and `cytoscape-cola@2.4.0`

Even after removing the nodes added with fixed x and y coordinates graph still looks the same (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Your graph is quite tall, with few nodes reaching far from the y-axis. This is why you are experiencing your problem. Normally cola results in a normal layout with spaced out nodes spanning to each corner, but I think you are adding nodes in your code manually with manual coordinates on the fixed x-coordinate 50. What does your graph look like if you skip these nodes/edges?

Comment: @StephanT. Even after removing nodes added with fixed co-ordinates, the graph looks the same. I have included a screenshot based on your feedback

Comment: Any resolution on this?